# Everything falls when I try a new magento theme

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I bought a magento theme (support 1.6.1 / 1.6.2). I have installed a new fresh magento with sample data and uploaded all theme files. When I create the configuration, everything falls.

Here is the error:

```
    Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 105: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: reference line 102 and block  in /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 431

#0 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(431): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/home/template/...', 431, Array)
#1 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(273): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->getFileLayoutUpdatesXml('fetchFileLayoutUpdates('frontend', 'default', 'e-shopping', '1')
#3 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(246): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchPackageLayoutUpdates()
#4 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(224): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->merge('default')
#5 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(307): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->load('default')
#6 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(109): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayoutUpdates()
#7 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage()
#8 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch()
#11 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match('index')
#12 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run()
#14 /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/index.php(80): Mage::run(Array)
#15 {main}
```

And this is the link: http://dev.template-tuners.com/gammadesign/magento/
How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your new layouts file is invalid.

Check it one by one in your IDE, you should see a invalid tag closing.

Comment: There's no problem in files. I get this when I update with 'e-shopping' (name of my theme), in Admin > Configuration > Design

Comment: Isn't your error clear enough ? : Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 105: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: reference line 102 and block  in /home/template/public_html/dev/gammadesign/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 431